# How to freeze the rotation of a Rigidbody2D within scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2d platformer, but lets say that if the character collides with any object, then it just rotates. Is there a way to set the rotation to 0? or keep it on 0?

Ive tried making the box collider far wider, it made my character alteast not fall after moving right/left, but thats not enough. It just falls over if there are any objects colliding with it, unless its taller than him.

Heres the code i try to use:

````
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{

//Movement
    public float speed;
    public float jump;
    float moveVelocity;

    //Grounded Vars
    bool grounded = true;

    void Update () 
    {
        //Jumping
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Z) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)) 
        {
            if(grounded)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x, jump);
            }
        }

        moveVelocity = 0;

        //Left Right Movement
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) 
        {
            moveVelocity = -speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) 
        {
            moveVelocity = speed;
        }

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (moveVelocity, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

    }
    //Check if Grounded
    void OnTriggerEnter2D()
    {
        grounded = true;
    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D()
    {
        grounded = false;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Rigidbody2D.freezeRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-freezeRotation.html).

Comment: Yeah, but basically it just doesnt work. Still the same as before, unless im doing something not right. I just put this `public bool freezeRotation = true;` in the first few lines, if its not right please tell me how should i make it.

Comment: Nevermind, it works within the Rigidbody2D component, but not within the script.

Comment: if you wanted to do it in the script you should put `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().freezeRotation = true;`. But for your case in the Inspector Tab should be fine.